# file_put_contents - blank file?

Tags: php, facebook, plaintext

The below script returns the facebook likes of a page in plaintext. I want to save this to a text file so i've added in the file_put_contents below. Its creating the textfile ok but is empty. When run without trying to save a file it works ok and displays the likes. Also other file_put_contents scripts i have running are working ok so not a permissions issue

```
<?php
  $page_id = "pageidhere";
  $xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
  $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
  $file = 'facebooklikes.txt';
  file_put_contents($file, $fans);  
?>
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

Tried this:

```
<?php
  $page_id = "pageidhere";
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
  $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
  echo $fans;
  $file = 'facebooklikes.txt';
  file_put_contents($file, $fans);  
?>
```

This shows the like count correctly but still doesn't add to the .txt file

Solved:

Thanks Jack

```
<?php
  $page_id = "pageidhere";
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
  $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
  echo $fans;
  $file = 'facebooklikes.txt';
  file_put_contents($file, (string)$fans);  
?>
```

Comment: Calling `@simplexml_load_file()` you are silencing all errors. Remove `@`.

Comment: Have you tried printing `$fans` ?

Comment: @user11153 - That didn't change anything

Comment: @Subhanker yes, which works. I just tried this which shows the count correctly but doesn't add it to the txt file.

        <?php
      $page_id = "pageidhere";
      $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
      $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
      echo $fans;
      $file = 'facebooklikes.txt';
      file_put_contents($file, $fans);  
    ?>

Comment: What happens if you `file_put_contents($file, (string)$fans);`?